# Set static IP using Cloud-Init on CentOS 7 with Terraform/KVM

Tags: networking, centos, terraform, centos7, cloud-init

I create a CentOS 7 VM using Terraform with [KVM](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt). As testserver, this VM should have a static IP which should be possible using [Cloud-Init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/18.5/topics/network-config-format-v2.html):

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  eth0:
    # match:
    #   name: eth0
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
    addresses: 
      - 10.18.3.2/24
    gateway4: 10.18.3.1
```

Now we re-create the VM and open its console:

```
terraform destroy -auto-approve
terraform apply -auto-approve
terraform console centos
```

This produces the following output from Cloud-Init

```
[   10.073544] cloud-init[626]: Cloud-init v. 18.5 running 'init-local' at Wed, 15 Jan 2020 17:34:43 +0000. Up 10.04 seconds.
[  OK  ] Started Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).
[  OK  ] Reached target Network (Pre).
         Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
See 'systemctl status network.service' for details.
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
         Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
         Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Dynamic System Tuning Daemon.
[  310.701064] cloud-init[820]: Cloud-init v. 18.5 running 'init' at Wed, 15 Jan 2020 17:39:44 +0000. Up 310.67 seconds.
[  310.724568] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[  310.727151] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: +--------+------+---------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
[  310.729810] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: | Device |  Up  |          Address          |    Mask   | Scope |     Hw-Address    |
[  310.732602] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: +--------+------+---------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
[  310.735405] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: |  eth0  | True | fe80::5054:ff:fe6a:ca6/64 |     .     |  link | 52:54:00:6a:0c:a6 |
[  310.738253] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |         127.0.0.1         | 255.0.0.0 |  host |         .         |
[  310.740787] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |          ::1/128          |     .     |  host |         .         |
[  310.743060] cloud-init[820]: ci-info: +--------+------+---------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
```

It took about 5 minutes at the line *[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking* to fail. As we can see, the machine doesn't have a ipc4 address assigned, as requested via Cloud-Init.

Why is my static IP address not assigned? I also tried `ens3` as interface name, without success.

### Terraforms `test.tf` file

```
provider "libvirt" {
  uri = "qemu:///system"
}
resource "libvirt_pool" "test_pool" {
  name = "test_pool"
  type = "dir"
  path = "/tmp/kvm_test"
}
resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-img" {
  name    = "centos7.qcow2"
  pool    = libvirt_pool.test_pool.name
  source =  "/var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2"
  format =  "qcow2"
}
data "template_file" "cloudinit_data" {
  template = file("cloudinit.cfg")
}
data "template_file" "cloudinit_network" {
  template = file("network.cfg")
}
resource "libvirt_cloudinit_disk" "cloudinit" {
  name           = "cloudinit.iso"
  # https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7919#issuecomment-320816276
  user_data      = data.template_file.cloudinit_data.rendered
  network_config = data.template_file.cloudinit_network.rendered
  pool           = libvirt_pool.test_pool.name
}

resource "libvirt_network" "test_network" {
   name = "test_network"
   addresses = ["10.18.3.0/24"]
   dhcp {
      enabled = false
   }
}
resource "libvirt_domain" "centos" {
  name   = "centos"
  memory = "1024"
  vcpu   = 4
  cloudinit = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloudinit.id

  network_interface {
    #network_name = "default"
    network_id = libvirt_network.test_network.id
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = libvirt_volume.centos7-img.id
  }

  console {
    type = "pty"
    target_type = "serial"
    target_port = "0"
  }
  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_type = "virtio"
    target_port = "1"
  }

  graphics {
    type = "spice"
    listen_type = "address"
    autoport = true
  }
}
```

### `cloudinit.cfg`

```
#cloud-config
# https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html
timezone: Europe/Berlin

fqdn: myhost.internal
manage_etc_hosts: true
resize_rootfs: true

ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa mykey

ssh_pwauth: true
password: password
chpasswd:
  list: |
    root:password
    centos:password
  expire: false

# Here I set the yum proxy and update all packages
# runcmd:
# ...
```

### Networking service logs

```
# systemctl status network.service -l
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2020-01-15 18:39:44 CET; 3min 11s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 654 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   CGroup: /system.slice/network.service
           └─1000 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient--eth0.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid -H myhost eth0

Jan 15 18:40:50 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:40:56 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:41:02 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:41:13 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:41:33 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:41:53 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:42:10 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:42:27 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:42:40 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x60f0f449)
Jan 15 18:42:49 myhost dhclient[1000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x60f0f449)
```

### Workaround: Dont use Cloud-Init for network config

Currently the only workaround I found is disabling the network part of Cloud-Init, which means not rendering the `network.cfg` file. Instead, setting a static IP in the `network_interface` section works:

```
resource "libvirt_domain" "centos" {
  name   = "centos"
  memory = "1024"
  vcpu   = 4
  cloudinit = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloudinit.id

  network_interface {
    network_id = libvirt_network.test_network.id

    hostname  = "centos"
    addresses = ["10.18.3.2"]
  }
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact same scenario and simply specifying dhcp4 or dhcp6 in the configuration file would cause the virtual machine to try to pull an address via dhcp (even with the value set to false.)

Workaround for me was to leave dhcp4 and dhcp6 out of the configuration file and everything worked as expected with a fast bootup and static network configuration in place.