# Assign static/DHCP IP from the hosts network to KVM VM provosioned by Terraform

Tags: ubuntu, networking, terraform, kvm, libvirt

I have a testserver connected to my home network with static IP address, virtualized with KVM/Libvirt. To test some services inside my network (e.g. with cell phones), I'd like to assign those VMs IPs from my SOHO router network - either statically or using the routers DHCP.

So my goals would be:

1. Assign a static IP outside of the routers DHCP scope (DHCP begins at 192.168.0.20, I use 192.168.0.10 in this example)
2. Get a dynamically IP from the router DHCP (accessable using DNS, so it would be no problem)

In both cases, the VM doesn't got an IP address:

[image]

Since those VMs got automatically provisioned by Terraform, I think SO is a good place for this problem.

**My Terraform POC file:**

```
terraform {
 required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    libvirt = {
      source  = "dmacvicar/libvirt"
      version = "0.6.2"
    }
  }
}

resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-img" {
  name    = "cnx_centos7.qcow2"
  pool    = libvirt_pool.default.name
  source =  "/var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2"
  format =  "qcow2"
}
provider "libvirt" {
  uri = "qemu:///system"
}
resource "libvirt_pool" "default" {
  name = "default"
  type = "dir"
  path = "/tmp/kvm"
}

data "template_file" "cloudinit_network" {
  template = file("network.cfg")
}
data "template_file" "cloudinit_data" {
  template = file("cloudinit.cfg")
  vars = {}
}

resource "libvirt_cloudinit_disk" "cloudinit" {
  name           = "cloudinit.iso"
  user_data      = data.template_file.cloudinit_data.rendered
  network_config = data.template_file.cloudinit_network.rendered
  pool           = libvirt_pool.default.name
}
resource "libvirt_network" "cnx_network" {
   name = "cnx_network"
   #addresses = ["192.168.0.17/24"]
   mode = "bridge"
   bridge = "br0"
   dhcp {
      enabled = true
   }
  # Enables usage of the host dns if no local records match
  dns {
    enabled = true
    local_only = false
  }
}

resource "libvirt_domain" "cnx" {
  name   = "cnx-poc"
  memory = 2048
  vcpu   = 4
  cloudinit = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloudinit.id

  network_interface {
    network_id = libvirt_network.cnx_network.id
    hostname  = "cnx.fritz.box"
    #addresses = ["192.168.0.10"]
    # Required to get ip address in the output when using dhcp
    wait_for_lease = true
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = libvirt_volume.centos7-img.id
  }

  console {
    type = "pty"
    target_type = "serial"
    target_port = "0"
  }
  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_type = "virtio"
    target_port = "1"
  }

  graphics {
    type = "spice"
    listen_type = "address"
    autoport = true
  }
}

output "ips" {
  value = libvirt_domain.cnx.*.network_interface.0.addresses
}
```

**Cloudinit `network.cfg`**

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: true
    dhcp6: false
    # addresses: 
    #   - 192.168.0.10
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
```

**Cloudinit `cloudinit.cfg`**

This is not really required here. I just set a password, so that I can access the VM using the libvirt console and look into the ip config, even when networking doesn't work.

```
#cloud-config
password: password
chpasswd:
  list: |
    root:password
    centos:password
  expire: false
```

**Network bridge `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` (Host)**

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp6s0:
          #addresses: []
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
    bridges:
      br0:
        interfaces: [enp6s0]
        addresses: [192.168.0.17/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.0.1
        #mtu: 1500
        nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.0.1]
          search: ["fritz.box"]
        parameters:
          stp: true
          #forward-delay: 4
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
    version: 2
```

Tested and applied with:

```
$ sudo netplan generate
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
```

### Other things I tried

Additional to the commented out lines in the config files, I tried the following things:

#### Directly referencing to the bridge

I tried to reference the bridge directly in the VM without defining a libvirt network like this:

```
resource "libvirt_domain" "cnx" {
  name   = "cnx-poc"
  memory = 2048
  vcpu   = 4
  cloudinit = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloudinit.id

  network_interface {
    bridge = "br0"
    addresses = ["192.168.0.10"]
  }
  # ...
```

This doesn't work and I think that's related to [this problem of the missing `qemu-guest-agent` package](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/issues/364#issuecomment-435923815). I can't simply solve this cause I need network access to install it, which doesn't work. I'll try to investigate if I could add two NICs (1x NAT 1x bridge) to have internet connection.

However this doesn't seem a good workaround. And in the ticket it's suggested to create a seperated network. I wouldn't have a problem with that workaround if it works, but I haven't luck with this so far.

#### Using no cloudinit/network

Cause I [run into this problem some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59757022/set-static-ip-using-cloud-init-on-centos-7-with-terraform-kvm), I tried NOT to specify the network config:

```
network_config = data.template_file.cloudinit_network.rendered
```

I assumed this may leads to let the VM use DHCP, or at least my static assigned IP from Terraform, seems not to work in this case.

#### Investigating the generated kvm objects

The generated network looks like this:

```
$ virsh net-dumpxml cnx_network
<network connections='1'>
  <name>cnx_network</name>
  <uuid>${removed}</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='br0'/>
</network>
```

This seems totally valid when looking at [articles like this](https://fabianlee.org/2019/04/01/kvm-creating-a-bridged-network-with-netplan-on-ubuntu-bionic/), who're explaining how to setup this manually with KVM and netplan on Ubuntu.

Also the `interface type='network'` element in the xml of the VM inspected with `virsh dumpxml cnx-poc` looks good:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='${mac}'/>
  <source network='cnx_network'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

### Some information about the environment

#### Host

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- Static IP 192.168.0.17/24
- Terraform v0.13.6
- provider registry.terraform.io/dmacvicar/libvirt v0.6.2
- virsh 4.0.0

#### VM

- CentOS 7 Cloudimage
- 192.168.0.10 tested as static IP (not reserved for the DHCP range)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that his problem was caused by an change of the [libvirt provider plugin](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt). Recently I updated from 0.5.2 to 0.6.2. With all releases newer than 0.4.2, the [default behavior was changed](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt#using-qemu-agent):

> Until terraform-provider-libvirt 0.4.2, qemu-agent was used by default
> to get network configuration. However, if qemu-agent is not running,
> this creates a delay until connecting to it times-out.
>
> In current versions, we default to not to attempt connecting to it,
> and attempting to retrieve network interface information from the
> agent needs to be enabled explicitly with qemu_agent = true, further
> details here. Note that you still need to make sure the agent is
> running in the OS, and that is unrelated to this option.
>
> Note: when using bridge network configurations you need to enable the
> qemu_agent = true. otherwise you will not retrieve the ip adresses of
> domains.
>
> Be aware that this variables may be subject to change again in future
> versions.

The [qemu-guest-agent](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Qemu-guest-agent) was already installed in the CentOS cloud image, so there is no need to download it. But because of the changed libvirt provider behavior, it wasn't used. I didn't noticed that yet cause my VMs were build with NAT. It only got relevant now for my change to the bridge network.

In fact this means, that I just have to add the property to my vm domain like this:

```
resource "libvirt_domain" "cnx" {
  name   = "cnx-poc"
  memory = 2048
  vcpu   = 4
  cloudinit = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloudinit.id
  # Required for bridged networks for libvirt provider plugin > 0.4.2
  qemu_agent = true
  # ...
}
```

Now my VMs were build and they get IP addresses of my DHCP server:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 8 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

ips = [
  [
    "192.168.0.163",
    "fe80::5054:ff:fe62:2adf",
  ],
]
ips_db2 = [
  [
    "192.168.0.162",
    "fe80::5054:ff:fe8a:ac6a",
  ],
]
```